# Two DNS servers for one domain

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

I had one server which acted as a dns and http server and one domain. Now I have two servers and some sites will be on a new server and the rest will still be on the old one. Is it possible to configure named on old box to ask the new one for all subdomains it doen't know about? I don't want to configure every new domain/subdomain (for sites I create on new one) on the old server's dns.

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest that you actually configure both DNS servers to host ALL records. That way you have redundancy and can lose a DNS server without taking out one or more of your domains.

The actual best practices for DNS are (not complete, but good general guidelines & starting point):

- Have at least 3 DNS servers
- Have them be on different network segments
- Have them be in different physical data centers (although if 2/3 of them are in one DC and the other one is in a separate DC just make sure the lonely DNS server can handle requests for all records)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify this in the named.conf  I do agree with what Zypher has mentioned and redundancy is a priceless investment.